# Drag and drop button on kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to drag and drop a button on a kendo grid 
and insert the row in a good position 
but how to do to insert the new row on end drag.

My sample is here :
https://dojo.telerik.com/@lgoubet/AweYIQaZ

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the row the element was dragged onto
2. Find the dataItem for the row by [grid.dataItem()](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/dataitem)
3. Get the dataItem's index through [dataSource.indexOf()](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/indexof)
4. Add a new row the the grid's dataSource through [dataSource.insert()](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/insert)